# Non-vanishing of intertwining operator - construction of Langlands quotient in Knapp's book

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I am reading theorem 7.24 in Knapp's book "Representation theory of semisimple groups". He wants to show that a relevant induction admits a unique irreducible quotient, by showing that any proper submodule lies in the kernel of the intertwining operator. But it seems that he omits the verification of this operator being non-zero, needed for that line of logic.

In Wallach's book this is shown, but he uses stronger results, namely some continuity, which he can do since he works with smooth vectors, not only K-finite ones.

Can I show that this intertwining operator is not zero, without developing more refined information about matrix coefficients? I want only to use K-finite matrix coefficients, and their asymptotic development.

Thanks,
Sasha

Comment: The $K$-finite vectors are smooth by a theorem of Harish-Chandra(?).

Comment: @Vít Tuček Yes.

Comment: His Lemma 7.23 relates the intertwining operator with certain limit. Maybe it is easier to prove that this limit could be nonzero.

Comment: @Vít Tuček I thought about this, but didn't see how to use it. In my "mini philosophy", the direction is opposite: I will read information about the limit from the non-vanishing (this will say that in some induced representations, one can find matrix coefficients of a certain growth rate exactly, not only less than or equal to it).